# Dynamic Column family in cassandra for feeds

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

In my use case I have to convert static columns (CQL3 CF) to dynamic columns (so that i can increase or decrease columns at run time). I,m working in DSE 4.5.

In that Column family I have to write feeds (data insertion will be real time).For example: CF will store feeds of users on the bases of user id & Timestamp and user1 can have 10 columns, user2 can have 20 columns,(every user columns can vary).

Currently in CQL3 CF,

```
CREATE TABLE USER_FEED (
userid int,
timestamp int,
col1 string,
col2 int,
col3 string,
....
PRIMARY KEY (userid,timestamp)
```

I have to design data model. I think I have to create Dynamic CF. But My question is can I combine rows to make row key? If yes, then How can I read data with combined rowkey And Can I store feed like data in Dynamic CF ? Is there any example or Use case available ?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly choose not to populate specific columns of a given row or delete one or more columns of existing rows, but all of the columns of all rows need to be declared when the table is created.

At the other end of the spectrum, you could just declare all of the user-variable data as a blob, but then you can't reference specific columns in a query.

Or... you could define a "user_data" column which is a map and then you can populate or delete elements of that map column. But then queries are more cumbersome and all of the pieces of user data would all have to have the same type, like string.

Or... you could go the blob route and use DSE/Solr with a field input transformer to extract the blob fields and populate Solr dynamic columns, which can then easily be queried.

Actually, the map column approach results in DSE/Solr implicitly creating Solr dynamic fields for each map element, so the difference between using a map or blob with field input transformer may be more a matter of preference and style and convenience.

How do you expect to query the data?

Comment: Jack, I have to search data with any key (for which I have create secondary indexes thru solr) and possibly require to perform analytic (join, calculations..) thru Hive or Shark.

Comment: Jack can you guide me How I can use DSE/Solr with a field input transformer to extract the blob fields and populate Solr dynamic columns, which can then easily be queried ?